# How to pass swift UITextField value to HTML Form Text in WKWebView Swift 3?

Tags: html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I have this HTML form:

```
  <p>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="result" name="Result" width="20"/>
    </form>
  </p>
```

How do I pass String value from my `UITextField` in swift to that form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ***evaluateJavaScript*** method like below.

```
class
ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet   weak    var oWV: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet   weak    var oTF: UITextField!
    override func
    viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        oWV.loadHTMLString( """
<p>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="result" name="Result" width="20"/>
    </form>
</p>
"""
        ,   baseURL: nil
        )
    }
    @IBAction func
    Do( _ p: Any ) {
        oWV.evaluateJavaScript(
            "document.querySelector( '#result' ).value='" + ( oTF.text ?? "" ) + "'"
        ) { p, e in
        }
    }
}
```